# org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration adding packages where Annotated classes resides

Tags: java, configuration, annotations, package, hibernate-4.x

I am creating database tables by the following code:

```
public void createSchema() {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.driver_class", driverClassName);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", url);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.username", username);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.connection.password", password);
    configuration.setProperty("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);

    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Base.class);
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(User.class);
    logger.info("begin database schema creation =========================");
    new SchemaUpdate(configuration).execute(true, true);
    logger.info("end database schema creation ===========================");
}
```

Here I have specified the Annotated classes names by `configuration.addAnnotatedClass` method. If I have 50 classes, then it will be really messy.

Is there any way to specify packages names for scanning for Annotated classes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with many of the changes in Hibernate 4, but there was no way to do this in Hibernate 3. I recommend using [Spring's excellent Hibernate support](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate), which [lets you scan packages for entities](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate4/LocalSessionFactoryBean.html#setPackagesToScan%28java.lang.String...%29), like you're asking for, and can manage a lot of other stuff for you, too, if you run your app in a Spring container.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Reflections to load all the Entities which are annotated as @Entity and add them to hibernate configuration. Chech the link fir a sample code
 [Hibernate 4 Annotation Configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11895205/hibernate-4-annotation-configuration)

Maddy