# Hibernate 4 Annotation Configuration

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations, hibernate-4.x, hibernate.cfg.xml

I'm trying to use Hibernate 4 with annotations only, and a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file.  I've made my own annotation and am using reflection to add this to the configuration.  I'm able to use Hibernate 4 in this manner fine, but my configuration is being built using a deprecated method.

```
final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(Item.class.getPackage().getName());
final Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
for (final Class<?> clazz : classes) {
    configuration.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
}
return configuration.configure().buildSessionFactory();
```

(Deprecated code: `buildSessionFactory();` ).

Even the hibernate 4 documentation shows to build the configuration in that manner.

If I try to use the new method (`buildSessionFactory(ServiceRegistry)`, I don't get the same result, and it seems like a lot of unnecessary code to do exactly what the deprecated method does anyway.  However, I don't want to keep using this style, because I dislike using deprecated code anyway.

*My question is:* How do I correctly configure Hibernate 4 from just a configuration file in the manner described above?  I seem to just cause errors & face unnecessary difficulties.

Comment: Have you had a look at this thread: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8621906/is-buildsessionfactory-deprecated-in-hibernate-4

There's a very well voted answer there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Modified code will look like below:-

```
  final Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    final Reflections reflections = new Reflections(Item.class.getPackage().getName());
    final Set<Class<?>> classes = reflections.getTypesAnnotatedWith(Entity.class);
    for (final Class<?> clazz : classes) {
        configuration.addAnnotatedClass(clazz);
    }
            ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry=new ServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings
(configuration.getProperties()).buildServiceRegistry();        

    return configuration.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
```

You may check following links for information: [HHH-6183](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-6183) and [HHH-2578](https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-2578).